# youtube-dl video title empty?

Tags: python, youtube, discord.py, audio-player, youtube-dl

So I am trying to get the video title and altough youtube-dl does have it, I can't/don't know how to grab it. When I run a command like `?play happy new year` This is what the console sends me:

```
, {'ext': 'vtt', 'url': 'https://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext?v=3Uo0JAUWijM&exp=xftt%2Cxctw&xoaf=5&hl=en&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1641179722&sparams=ip%2Cipbits%2Cexpire%2Cv%2Cexp%2Cxoaf&signature=92DD5869242040ADCF3731AB6495EA9A97EEFFFA.70A356834E9214E33A5D53B3584F4E42EA2BFAC4&key=yt8&lang=en&name=English&fmt=vtt'}]}, 'like_count': 409108, 'channel': 'ABBA', 'track': 'Happy New Year', 'artist': 'ABBA', 'album': 'Happy New Year', 'creator': 'ABBA', 'alt_title': 'Happy New Year', 'extractor': 'youtube', 'webpage_url_basename': '3Uo0JAUWijM', 'extractor_key': 'Youtube', 'n_entries': 1, 'playlist': ' happy new year', 'playlist_id': ' happy new year', 'playlist_title': None, 'playlist_uploader': None, 'playlist_uploader_id': None, 'playlist_index': 1, 'thumbnail': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi_webp/3Uo0JAUWijM/maxresdefault.webp', 'display_id': '3Uo0JAUWijM', 'requested_subtitles': None, 'asr': 48000, 'filesize': 4498340, 'format_id': '251', 'format_note': 'tiny', 'fps': None, 'height': None, 'quality': 0, 'tbr': 133.928, 'url': 'https://rr5---sn-qxoedn7k.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1641176122&ei=2gfSYarKJMmE6QLT95eQCQ&ip=146.148.70.28&id=o-ANcmPwbdYgcbTfqk5jwpB6-6rZIFKd0y7zqhxGcuXpzm&itag=251&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=vO&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-qxoedn7k%2Csn-qxo7rn7s&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=5&pl=20&gcr=us&initcwndbps=225000&vprv=1&mime=audio%2Fwebm&ns=nadM4zgbYfc8e3L1cksghXMG&gir=yes&clen=4498340&dur=268.701&lmt=1640871470575705&mt=1641154148&fvip=5&keepalive=yes&fexp=24001373%2C24007246&c=WEB&txp=4532434&n=JA2xpSWafI7GU8jU&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cgcr%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cns%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRgIhAJ-V4oH6DLeY31dcATbD5jm92e5qIDsXJCV0B1hx9Z5oAiEA2_3qpwdFBfOQ1pEZ3KYyfxMyDWmXm9cZiDn-8BMwYgU%3D&sig=AOq0QJ8wRAIgfboFf8doHlVs1HiHFQskDvJ8jjGbuH2Cs7xLAaV3QLoCIEhXa14PH6Mm5rhpViv0KAQOIkMsE-nEGPPFQlpzSYjD', 'width': None, 'ext': 'webm', 'vcodec': 'none', 'acodec': 'opus', 'abr': 133.928, 'downloader_options': {'http_chunk_size': 10485760}, 'container': 'webm_dash', 'format': '251 - audio only (tiny)', 'protocol': 'https', 'http_headers': {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.50 Safari/537.36', 'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7', 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept-Language': 'en-us,en;q=0.5'}}
None
```

I don't show the rest cuz that is just a long mess, but as you can see it has the things like like count, channel name etc.

I used

```
video_title = info.get('title', None)
print(video_title)
```

To grab the video title, but it prints None.

How do I make it so it prints the video title?

This is my code:

```
@commands.command()
  async def play(self, ctx, *, arg): 
    if ctx.author.voice is None:
      await ctx.send("Join a voice channel dumb fuck")
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if ctx.voice_client is None:
      await voice_channel.connect()
    else:
      await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
    ctx.voice_client.stop()
    try:
      requests.get("" + str(arg))
    except: arg = " " + str(arg)
    else: arg = "" + str(arg)
    YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
    vc = ctx.voice_client
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    youtube_dl_opts = {}
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
      info = ydl.extract_info(f"ytsearch:{arg}", download=False)
      if 'entries' in info:
        video = info['entries'][0]
      else:
        video = info
      url2 = video['formats'][0]['url']
      print(video)
      video_url = video['url']
      #print(video_url)
      source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
      vc.play(source)
      video_title = info.get('title', None)
      print(video_title)
      await ctx.send(video_title)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use -

```py
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
      info = ydl.extract_info(f"ytsearch:{arg}", download=False)
      if 'entries' in info:
        video = info['entries'][0]
      else:
        video = info
      url2 = video['formats'][0]['url']
      print(video)
      video_url = video['url']
      #print(video_url)
      source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2,**FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
      vc.play(source)
      video_title = info['title'] # Getting video title
      print(video_title) # printing video title ...
      await ctx.send(video_title)
```

Just put - `video_title = info['title']`
instead of - `video_title = info.get('title', None)`

If that doesn't work, then make it a string -

```py
video_title = f"{info['title']}"
print(video_title)
```

I hope this Helps ...